# Butterknife Fragment Button not working

Tags: android, fragment, butterknife

I have a Fragment that I am using Butterknife with.

```
public class FooFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foo, container, false);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.some_btn)
    public void someButtonOnClick() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

However, the someButtonOnClick method is never called when the button is tapped on the screen.

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong with the Butterknife framework?

Here is the layout that is being used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/some_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/some_btn_selection" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/some_other_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/xsmall_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/some_other_btn_selection" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated (since it would result in a compile error), but any chance you're trying to do this in a library project (vs a normal android app project)? ButterKnife flat-out won't work inside library projects because their R.id's are not final.

2nd Question, are you subclassing this fragment and expecting this to work? I have a feeling that ButterKnife annotations (like OttoBus) are only valid on the actual class being instantiated. If you are subclassing this fragment, then try re-implementing the someButtonOnClick method (with the annotation) in the subclass to confirm the issue.

Comment: Show your me R.layout.foo

Comment: No, it is not part of a library, nor is my Fragment class subclassed from any class other than Fragment.

Comment: I also tried placing a ButterKnife.inject(this) within the onCreate of the Activity, thinking that ButterKnife needed it for the containing activity but alas, there was no joy.  I still cannot get it to work for Fragments, just Activity.

Comment: what solution you get for this, I am also facing same

Answer (score 4):

Just use this structure:

```
@OnClick(R.id.some_btn)
public void someButtonOnClick(View view) {
    // do something
}
```

This is described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issue. Clean the project and try to run. It should fix. If you still have issue, call `someButtonOnClick()` in `onCreate` and run and remove it and again run it. It should work. It worked for me.