# Using Butterknife in Android

Tags: android, onclick, butterknife

I am trying to use Butterknife in Android, it does not seem to work. could you guide me where I am doing it wrong.

I tried to place a debug point in inside 'OnClick', but does not seem to come there.

Gradle dependencies (app)

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

activity_main.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_frg_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Fragment One"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_frg_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Frag Two"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@OnClick({R.id.btn_frg_one, R.id.btn_frg_two})
    public void addFrgToCon(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_frg_one:
                addFragment(new FOne());
                break;
            case R.id.btn_frg_two:
                addFragment(new FTwo());
                break;
        }
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126066/butterknife-fragment-button-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you forgot this

**`ButterKnife.bind(this);`**

for more information read **[Butternife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)**

Comment: @BRDroid did you add this **ButterKnife.bind(this);**

Comment: That was the problem. thank you Prem, could you update your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
> use ButterKnife.bind(this);
> 
> 
> Other provided binding APIs:
> 
>     Bind arbitrary objects using an activity as the view root. If you use a pattern like MVC you can bind the controller using its activity
> with ButterKnife.bind(this, activity).
> 
>     Bind a view's children into fields using ButterKnife.bind(this). If you use <merge> tags in a layout and inflate in a custom view
> constructor you can call this immediately after. Alternatively, custom
> view types inflated from XML can use it in the onFinishInflate()
> callback.
```